# regular expression selecting a group

Tags: regex, hive, grouping

In hive, I have a field with group delimiter '^' and field in the group delimited by '~', Sample values:

```
1~~0~4~6^7~~0~3~4^19~~1~4~6^88~~0~4~6^1~~0~4~6
5~~0~4~6^8~~0~3~4^5~~0~4~6^88~~0~4~6^18~~3~4~4^99~~4~5~8
```

I need to select all the groups which has non zero value in the third field.

Example :

```
1~~0~4~6^7~~0~3~4^19~~**1**~4~6^88~~0~4~6^1~~0~4~6
```

Here `19~~1~4~6` will be selected since third field is 1

```
5~~0~4~6^8~~0~3~4^5~~0~4~6^88~~0~4~6^18~~**3**~4~4^99~~**4**~5~8
```

Here `18~~3~4~4` and `99~~4~5~8` and will be selected.

How the regular expression be formed, since there is "if" condition here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[0-9]*~[0-9]*~[1-9][0-9]*~[0-9]*~[0-9]*
```

This doesn't care about group delimiter. It just finds any sequence of alternating ~ and numbers, where middle one is not empty nor zero.

#### Regex explained:

```
[0-9]*        - match zero or more numbers
~             - match literal ~ character
[0-9]*
~
[1-9][0-9]*   - match one character between 1 and 9 followed by zero or more numbers (basically it means 'match any number but it can't start with zero)
~
[0-9]*
~
[0-9]*
```

If your input is always formatted the same as in your example, this will work. If for example one group will contain more or less field delimiters ~, than it will need some tuning.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  pe.val
from    mytable t lateral view posexplode (split(t.str,'\\^')) pe
where   split(pe.val,'~')[2] <> '0'
```

---

```
+-----------+
|    val    |
+-----------+
| 19~~1~4~6 |
| 18~~3~4~4 |
| 99~~4~5~8 |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank you @Dudu Markovitz, your answer helped me, almost there, but I have to select other fields as well in the same query, and if the split value is null, in that case also it should be selected. select id, pe.val from    mytable t lateral view posexplode (split(t.str,'\\^')) pe
where   split(pe.val,'~')[2] <> '0'
in the above query id will not be selected if pe.val is null.